# I need to upgrade mapbox from 7.x to 8.x

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am upgrading mapbox version from 7.x to 8.x. On the gradle files, there is also `'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.2.9'`

Should this be upgraded to latest version too? If yes, could somebody help me the find the migration guide or is it not needed?

Comment: upgrade everything to the latest version, unless you have a reason not to

Comment: @TimCastelijns how can I know that I can safely upgrade without there being any migration guide, I am afraid I might break something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`7.x` to `8.x` did not bring any breaking changes in the APIs, the only change being [the pricing](http://blog.mapbox.com/new-pricing-46b7c26166e7). `mapbox-android-services` is long deprecated, you should use [Mapbox Java SDK](http://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/overview) instead.

Comment: Is there something i should keep in mind while replacing mapbox-android-services with mapbox-sdk-services?

Comment: It's split into smaller packages now, so you can include only the ones, that you're actually using. There have also been public API changes, but following compile errors should lead you to a clean resolution - there wasn't a lot or even none major behavioral changes.